# The type or namespace name 'Outlook' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Inte rop'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, msbuild, office-interop

The project builds just fine locally, however when we attempt to have our build server build it the following error is generated.

*error CS0234: The type or
namespace name 'Outlook' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Inte
rop' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

The reference is correctly set in the project and the using statement is also set, the Outlook PIA has been installed on the build server.
The using statement: `using Outlook_IntOp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

We also are already using the Excel Interop and its been building fine, every reference to outlook is just like the excel references.

Everything I have found so far point to adding the reference to the project, it is there and builds fine locally.  This error only occurs on the build server which does not have Office or visual studio loaded.

Anyone have any ideas what might be happening here and how to get around it.  Installing Office and Visual Studio really isn't an option afforded to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your project has the reference to an existing interop dll, **not** to the actual COM server object ("Microsoft Outlook" on the COM tab in VS Project References dialog). In the latter case the interop gets regenerated and you will have problems if Outlook is not installed on your builder machine.

Comment: The way we added the reference was to Navigating from the Solution Explorer, Project->Reference->Add Reference Selected the .NET tab -> Browsed to and selected Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. Are you saying I should use the Browse tab and navigate to the folder containing the actual interop dll?

Comment: Unless the interop dll is in GAC on the builder machine, yes, add the interop dll as part of your project and reference it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, and report how it works out.

Comment: This solved the build problem; now I have a different problem which I'll chase down.  Thanks Dimitry